# TempDb growing Big on Staging server version SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-administration

I have a concern regarding `Tempdb` growth on one of my staging servers. Current size of `Tempdb` has grown to nearly 42 GB in size.

Per standards we have split the data file into a primary `.mdf` and 7 `.ndf` files along a `.ldf`. Currently all the 7 `.ndf` are more than 4 GB, and primary being over 6GB.

1. Tried restarting but it fills up fast.
2. DBCC shrink file (`.ndf`) is also not helping as it will shrink max to some MB.

Kindly help on how to resolve this..

Thanks 
Kapil..

Comment: DBA question should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)